# Issue getting user info from user registration, and HTML view problem

Tags: angular

Ok so the first problem I was getting was "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'FirstName' of undefined", so I tried to look for a solution online, but I could not find one that fixed my issue. What I did try is adding `*ngIf="user"` to the input tags, that seems to erase the web console error, but it seems like there is an issue outputting the html, it looks like this:

[image]

But, its supposed to look like this:
[image]

I am really not sure, if I am setting up the components correctly, I would like to know how to solve this problem?

**sign-up.component.html**

```
<div class="row">      
    <div class="card">          
        <div class="sm-jumbotron center-align">              
          <h2>User Registration</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form [formGroup]="userRegistrationForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"  autocomplete="off">
        <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">   
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="FirstName" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.FirstName" >          
        </div>
          <div class="input-field col s6">
            <label>Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" formControlName="LastName" *ngIf="user" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.LastName">                
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <label data-error="Required Field">Username</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Username" *ngIf="user" [(ngModel)]="user.UserName">                  
              </div>
            </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="Password" *ngIf="user" [(ngModel)]="user.Password">            
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <label data-error="Invalid email">Email</label>
              <input type="text" formControlName="Email" *ngIf="user" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.Email" [pattern]="emailPattern">                
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn-large btn-submit" *ngIf="user" [disabled]="!userRegistrationForm.valid">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            </form>
          </div>
```

**sign-up.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../shared/user.model';
import { NgForm, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserService } from '../shared/user.service';
import {ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-up', //used in app.component.html
  templateUrl: './sign-up.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-up.component.css']
})
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
  user:User;
  userRegistrationForm: FormGroup;
  emailPattern = "^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$";

  constructor(private userService:UserService, private toastr: ToastrService, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createRegisterForm();
  }

  createRegisterForm() {
    this.userRegistrationForm = this.fb.group({
      FirstName: ['', Validators.required],
      LastName:  ['', Validators.required],
      Username:  ['', Validators.required],
      Password:  ['', Validators.required],
      Email: ['', Validators.required]
  });
} 

  onSubmit(form:FormGroup) {
    if (this.userRegistrationForm.valid) {
      //this.user = Object.assign({}, this.userRegistrationForm.value);
      this.userService.registerUser(this.user).subscribe((data:any) => {      
        this.toastr.success("User Registration Successful"); 
      }, error => {
        this.toastr.error(error);
    }); 
    }
  }


}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from './user.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  readonly rootUrl = "http://localhost:5000/" //connect to API
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  registerUser(user : User) : Observable<User> 
  {
    const body : User = {
      FirstName:user.FirstName,
      LastName:user.LastName,
      UserName: user.UserName,
      Password: user.Password,
      Email: user.Email      
    }
    return this.http.post<User>(this.rootUrl + 'api/User/Register', body);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete *ngIf=“user” and ngModel from all the form controls

In onSubmit method create a request object

```
onSubmit() {
Let request : User = new User();
request.FirstName= this.userRegistrationForm.get(‘FirstName’).value

// create all the four values here like firstname 
      this.userService.registerUser(request).subscribe((data:any) => {      
        this.toastr.success("User Registration Successful"); 
      }, error => {
        this.toastr.error(error);
    }); 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

remove `[(ngModel)]` on your input elements and uncomment

```
this.user = Object.assign({}, this.userRegistrationForm.value);
```

I think it will work then

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate your user. That's where your error was coming from, your tried accessing the property of something that was undefined, namely the user variable.

Add this to your ngOnInit:

```
this.user = {
    FirstName: '',
    LastName: '',
    Username: '',
    Password: '',
    Email: '',
}
```

However, you also have `ngModel` and `formControl` conflicting on your inputs, you can't use both at the same time as mentioned by @Prasanth in his answer.